# Elixir - what's the guiding philisophy behind using :erlang.float_to_binary/2 directly?

Tags: erlang, elixir

I've recently started learning Elixir and I'm puzzled by the arbitrary-looking divide between things that are available as Elixir modules vs. direct calls to Erlang libs.

Particularly I've noticed that formatting a `Float` into a string/binary is best done (in recent versions of Elixir) by directly calling the following function:

`:erlang.float_to_binary/2`

Perusing older questions and forum posts, I've seen several Elixir functions doing the above job (and sometimes just calling the above function) that were obsoleted and removed from Elixir.

What's the system in deciding which functions get an Elixir wrapper/implementation vs. direct calls to Erlang libs?

One reason I'm confused is that 'rendering a float as a string' feels like an incredibly basic language function, so I feel that I'm missing something when I see that Elixir doesn't provide it 'natively'.

Comment: I think [this article](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/erlang-libraries.html) sums it up. Most basic functionalities are covered by Elixir modules (`String`, `Map`, `Float`...) but Elixir doesn't wrap erlang libraries such as `:math`, `:rand`, `:crypto`... just for the sake of wrapping.`

Answer (score 3):

It seems Elixir’s [`Float.to_string/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Float.html#to_string/1) is better for this.

Comment: It's a built-in Elixir function indeed, but it won't allow you to specify any options (like the number of decimals). 

I think the article that @sabiwara linked in the OP comment explains it best: `In fact, Elixir discourages simply wrapping Erlang libraries in favor of directly interfacing with Erlang code. In this section, we will present some of the most common and useful Erlang functionality that is not found in Elixir.`

So far I haven't found any deeper philosophy behind this :)